# SQL Relations many to many giving one element only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have a SQL table that is made up of two columns without column id the two columns is combining of equivalent parts of cars in which it is necessary to return in one column all possible relations giving an element of one column or another, for example the given value is 530:

```
 ColunaA    ColunaB 
 530          520
 530          510
 530          444
 444          222
 333          111
```

The end result has to be:

```
 Column X 
 530 
 520 
 510  
 444 
 222
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
WITH AreasCTE AS 
(
 SELECT colunaa, colunab FROM dbo.Tabela1 WHERE colunaa = '530' 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT a.colunaa, a.colunab FROM dbo.Tabela1 a 
 INNER JOIN AreasCTE s ON a.colunaa = s.colunaa
) 
SELECT top 100 colunaa, colunab FROM AreasCTE
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: No ID column or similar?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please make an [MCVE] with sample input in the shape of a line of "create table ..." and some lines of "insert ...".

Comment: Does not look like combinations, looks like a list of occuring entries.

Comment: Why has the desired output "530" twice but not three times and "444" only once and neither "333" nor "111"? Please explain more about the logic of the result.

Comment: No id column is all free combining code parts of cars, we just need the result of all the compatible parts with giving one part only

Comment: Please show your own attempts to solve this. Did you play with a combination of obvious keywords? E.g. "UNION", "DISTINCT", maybe "JOIN" (but the latter does not match the desired output).

Comment: As long as desired output and description of its logic are that much in conflict, the question is unclear.

Comment: I removed unrelated tags. Feel free to add them again, accompanied by an explanation of their relevance in this question.

Comment: the product is sql server  - T-SQL

Comment: Why is "222" in desired output, but not "111" and not "333"?

Comment: 111 and 333 is not in desired output because is not compatible with the other elements

Comment: Explain how the desired output changes in case another line is added "222, 333". That might help guessing the actual logic.

Comment: What happens if the line "530, 444" is removed? Am I guessing correctly that the desired output then does not contain "444" anymore and also not "222" anymore?

Comment: if "222,333" is added the output need to include "333" and "111" because it have the "222" that is compatible with "444" so the "111" is compatible too

Comment: if "530,444" is removed the output is only "530,520,510"

Comment: OK. Now explain that in the question. Define the significance of two numbers in one row. Mention the transitive meaning, i.e. if each of two numbers are comatible to a third one, then the pair is compatible, too. Make a [MCVE], because I need something to test my solution on. "Recursion" might after all actually be an appicable tag.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt the code below but i can't do that at the moment:WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        table1.colunaA Group_ID,
        table1.colunab
    FROM table1 M1
        LEFT JOIN table1 M2
            ON M1.colunaA = M2.colunab
    WHERE M2.colunaA IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.Group_ID,
        M.colunab
    FROM CTE C
        JOIN table1 M
            ON C.Group_ID = M.colunab
)
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY Group_ID    yes recursion is the way i go

Comment: i work with that too: WITH AreasCTE AS
(SELECT colunaa,colunab
FROM dbo.Tabela1 WHERE colunaa = '530'
 UNION ALL SELECT a.colunaa,a.colunab FROM dbo.Tabela1 a 
 INNER JOIN AreasCTE s ON a.colunaa = s.colunaa)
  SELECT top 100 colunaa,colunab
  FROM AreasCTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's not perfect solution probably needs some performance tuning but should do the job.

```
    DECLARE @t1 TABLE
    (
        colunaA NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        colunaB NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES ( 530, 520 ) ,
       ( 530, 510 ) ,
       ( 530, 444 ) ,
       ( 444, 222 ) ,
       ( 333, 111 );

SELECT *
FROM   @t1;

DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @value = 222;

DECLARE @filter TABLE
    (
        id NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @filter
VALUES ( @value );

DECLARE @right_row_count INT;
DECLARE @left_row_count INT;

SET @left_row_count = 1;


WHILE @left_row_count > 0
      OR @right_row_count > 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @filter ( id )
                    SELECT DISTINCT t.colunaA
                    FROM   @t1 t
                           INNER JOIN @filter f ON t.colunaB = f.id
                    WHERE  t.colunaA NOT IN (   SELECT *
                                                FROM   @filter );
        SET @right_row_count = @@rowcount;

        INSERT INTO @filter ( id )
                    SELECT DISTINCT t.colunaB
                    FROM   @t1 t
                           INNER JOIN @filter f ON t.colunaA = f.id
                    WHERE  t.colunaB NOT IN (   SELECT *
                                                FROM   @filter );
        SET @left_row_count = @@rowcount;


    END;

SELECT   *
FROM     @filter
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: it works in the direction of searching only column A but how it works when i search 444

Comment: yes i delete the comment i figured it out...just a dummie question sorry. but the searching on both directions is needed

Comment: both directions added

Comment: WORK LIKE A CHARM!! Thanks for the reply